# Understanding Backslash Behaviour (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, path

I declare variable 'path'

```
path = "C:\\dir\\file.zip"
```

Because the first slash escapes the second, and so

```
print path
>>>C:\dir\file.zip
```

However, when I try to unzip the file

```
inF = gzip.GzipFile(path, 'rb')
```

I get the error

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\dir\\file.gz'
```

How are these additional backslashes appearing, and how can I fix it?

TIA

Comment: The additional backslashes are appearing because the error message is using the `repr` version of the path passed to it.

Comment: The easier way is to replace the backslash with the forward slash. Windows and linux should both work with forward slashes.

Comment: @JustinEngel Changing the slashes will not *explain* the situation though. After all, the question is about *understanding* what’s going on. Avoiding it by using different slashes does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those additional backslashes are there to make the string unambiguous, as it might have contained quotes, newlines and such. IOError has printed the `repr` form of the string, such that the value can be recreated by copying it into Python code:

```
>>> path = "C:\\dir\\file.zip"
>>> print path
C:\dir\file.zip
>>> print repr(path)
'C:\\dir\\file.zip'
```

So the extra backslashes are simply the same escaping you did in the first place, and have no impact on the error itself.

Answer (score 1):

'\' is used to vanish the special meaning of any character like `''` or `""` or '\' and manu other.

`rawstring` do the same for you [check here](http://www.interfaceware.com/manual/python_escape_sequences_raw_strings.html)

instead

```
path = "C:\\dir\\file.zip"
path = r'C:\dir\file.zip'

>>> print 'C:\\dir\\file.zip'
C:\dir\file.zip

>>> print (r'C:\Users\dir\file.zip') 
C:\dir\file.zip

>>> print (ur'C:\\Users\dir\file.zip') #ur'' as unicode string literals with \u or \U sequences are broken in python2 and several backslashes are treated as one on windows
```

Use forward slashes rahter than backward slashes

```
   >>> a = 'C:/User/dir/file.zip'
   >>> a
    'C:/User/dir/file.zip'
```

Comment: They are exactly the same thing.

Comment: Python 2 raw unicode strings are broken. Try `ur"\Users"`

Comment: @SmitJohnth in python2 `str` use bytestring and here bytestring are given so i think not to worry about unicode here but thanks for advice i update my code.

Comment: From the question, it seems obvious that OP is aware of how escaping characters works. Using raw strings here provides no difference to OP’s solution and does not explain the result OP is seeing.

Comment: @poke i updated the code and give the solution of problem. please check.

Comment: The answer is still not attempting to *explain* what’s going on but instead just proposes a workaround to hide the issue.